# Java - mooc.fi - Exercise 46: Film Reference - method returning a map cannot return null

Tags: java, null, return

I do have a method:

```
public Map<Film, Rating> getPersonalRatings(Person person){

    return this.personalRatings.get(person);
}
```

So, the basic concept is there's a

```
HashMap personalRatings <Person, Map<Film, Rating>>
```

that includes another HashMap of film ratings as map values.

My method needs to return a Map of rated films and so it does. The question is, what should it return if a person never rated a single film and tho the HashMap of film ratings is null. A null cannot be returned.

Comment: How about an empty map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning null where a collection is expected is not a good practice. Normally, this should be an empty collection. In this case, using Java 8, you can use

```
this.personalRatings.getOrDefault(person, Collections.emptyMap());
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid null, you could use the `computeIfAbsent()` method.

For example this :

```
Map<Film, Rating> ratingByFilmForThisPerson = 
                 personalRatings.computeIfAbsent(person, k -> new HashMap<Film, Rating>());
```

returns the actual map for the person if a mapping exists.
Otherwise it creates and associates an empty map for the person.
In any case it returns the value :